# What does tilde(~) operator do?

Tags: c, cryptography

I recently saw the above operator in a code,I googled for it but found nothing.The code is below.Please describe what actually does this operator do?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned long int i=0;
     char ch;
    char name1[20],name2[20];
    FILE *fp,*ft;
    printf("ENTER THE SOURCE FILE:");
    gets(name1);
    printf("ENTER THE DESTINATION FILE:");
    gets(name2);
    fp=fopen(name1,"r");
    ft=fopen(name2,"w");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("CAN,T OPEN THE FILE");
    }
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
         ch=getc(fp);
         ch=~((ch^i));/*<--Here*/
        i+=2;
        if(i==100000)
        {
             i=0;
        }
     putc(ch,ft);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(ft);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: searching ~ in google ? ~, which is known as the tilde or synonym operator for google search. if you search ~search surprisingly it gives yahoo :-) you need to search tidle

Comment: Related - [How does the bitwise complement (~) operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-work)

Comment: Not related to your question, but you might want to read [Why is while(!feof(fp)) always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The `~` operator in C++ (and other C-like languages like C and Java) performs a [bitwise NOT operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operators#NOT) - all the 1 bits in the operand are set to 0 and all the 0 bits in the operand are set to 1. In other words, it creates the *complement* of the original number.

For example:

```
10101000 11101001 // Original  (Binary for -22,295 in 16-bit two's complement)
01010111 00010110 // ~Original (Binary for  22,294 in 16-bit two's complement)
```

In your example, `ch=~((ch^i))` performs a bitwise NOT on the [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operators#XOR) of `ch` and `i` then assigns the result to `ch`.

The bitwise NOT operator has an interesting property that when applied on numbers represented by [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), it changes the number's sign and then subtracts one (as you can see in the above example).

You may want become familiar with [the different operators of the C++ language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) since it is difficult to search for operators on search engines. Better yet, you can get [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which will tell you about the C++ operators.

Comment: Is there any search engine that allows searching for symbols?

Comment: @Jon Rodriguez: None that I know of. If you need to look up a symbol or operators for a particular programming languages, it's best to simply search for the language (like "C++ programming language").

Comment: There's [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) but I can't vouch for its helpfulness in finding out *about* symbols so much as for finding out their use cases ;)

Comment: @Jon: It helps if you know the name of the glyph Googl'ing "C code tilde" will yield an answer.  But then again so would have "C programming language operators" - sure you'd get *all* the operators, but that is narrow enough to find an answer I suggest!

Comment: @Insilico Although the nut-and-bolt details of your answer are correct, a *not* (`!`) operation is not the same as an *invert* (`~`) operation.  *not* (`!`) is used on logical expressions to invert the logic resultant, whereas *invert* (`~`) is used to flip a variable's bits between 0 and 1.  The usage of *not* (`!`) is also hardware dependent, so I personally don't recommend its usage.  Another way to think of using the the *invert* (`~`) operator is that it is functionally the same as doing an *exclusive-or* (`^`) of your variable against the one's compliment of zero: `~0x81 = 0x81 ^ 0xFF`

Answer (score 21):

The ~ operator inverts all the bits. So `10000001` becomes `01111110`.

Answer (score 14):

It is the bitwise complement operator. Given the input

> 010011101

returns the output:

> 101100010