# what does ~ on an integer value do?usage of this operation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I wanted to know what does ~ operation on int value does.
I coded and printed ~a with a assigned as 3 and it gave -4.
Please tell me its usage.

Comment: The answer is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952122/what-does-operator-do][1]

Comment: @user2120978, exactly! How could it possibly be the first time someone asks this.

Comment: Thanks , but none i was able to find here quickly. so thought of posting it again.

Answer (score 6):

`~` is bitwise NOT operator (complement). It toggles bit `0` to `1` and `1` to `0`.  On a 32 bit machine decimal `3` is

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011  (2's complement)
```

The bitwise complement is equal to the two's complement of the value minus one (`~x = −x − 1`). Therefore `~3` is

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111100 = -4
```

Answer (score 3):

Unary operator that produces the bitwise NOT or complement of a binary value.

In your case using a signed integer:

```
 a = 3 = 0b00000011

~a = -4 = 0b11111100
```

Comment: It's an operator, not an operand

Comment: Thanks Pat, edited as per suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It's the unary complement operator, or bitwise not operator. It flips all the bits in a number.

In the case of signed integers, usually the highest bit stores the sign (two's complement storage), so complementing a positive number yields a negative one, and vice-versa (except for 0 and the minimum negative value).

Answer (score 1):

It is the bitwise complement operator. More information can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxt4z71k.aspx), but essentially as has been stated by the other answers it flips the binary bits of, in your example, an integer from either `0` to `1` or `1` to `0`.

An example would be if you had the decimal value `15` represented in binary format as

```
1111
```

and if you were to take the bitwise complement of `15` like `~15` the binary format of that would produce

```
0000
```

which is obviously `0` in decimal.

Comment: The `~15 == 0` example only works on 4-bit unsigned integers, which don't normally appear in C (other than structure bitfields).

Comment: @pat you're absolutely correct. I was only using it as an example of how the bits change via the complement.

Answer (score 1):

One's complement. ~ flips the bits. In your example, **00000011** is changed to **11111100**, assuming it's an 8 bit number.

Refer to the following chart of Bitwise operations in C.

[image]

Comment: Can the person who downvoted my answer tell me what needs to be edited?

Answer (score 1):

~ is bitwise NOT operator, this flips the bit pattern. Assume the bit value is 1010, this bitwise NOT operator will flip the pattern to 0101

Answer (score 0):

Inverts all the bits, it turns `00010101` -> `11101010` for example

Answer (score 0):

The `~` operator takes an operand of any integer type, and returns the inverted-bit value.

It does not change the value of the operand itself (in opposed to `++` and `--`, for example).

It is useful mostly for bit masking.

**Example #1:**

- Compute a mask with bit #5 set to 0 and all other bits set to 1:

  `int mask = ~(1<<5);`
- Given an integer variable `x`, set all bits to 1 and keep bit #5 at its current value:

  `x |= mask;`

**Example #2:**

- Compute a mask with bit #5 set to 1 and all other bits set to 0:

  `int mask = (1<<5);`
- Given an integer variable `x`, set all bits to 0 and keep bit #5 at its current value:

  `x &= ~mask;`

It is also quite useful on beginner job interviews...