# Bitwise operators: Printing the numbers 1 to 100 using bit manipulation

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I believe it is possible to generate the numbers 1 to 100 using bitwise operations or bit manipulation, rather than by the traditional increment instruction.

What are the possible methods of doing this?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Why would you use a bitwise operator to print numbers from 1 to 100?

Comment: doesn't make any sense?i don't think so.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck there is no practical purpose for this. No sane person would use bitwise operators to do such a simple thing. The purpose for this is to see whether the person knows about bitwise operators and what they do. Most probably this is some sort of the interview question.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question.

Comment: "I believe it is possible ..." followed by "send me ur codez". Can I say "I believe it is possible to predict tomorrow's lottery numbers" and ask for a listing of all methods as well? (I'd be very happy with just *one* that works.)

Comment: Yes, this is surely interview/assignment garbage.  It might be interesting, but I can't see how it's any kind of useful addition to a knowledge repo.  I'm gonna downClose.

Answer (score 4):

I believe there are a couple of ways to achieve it. One of them is to use [tilde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952122/what-does-operator-do) operator `~x` which is a bitwise complement and equal to `-(x+1)`

```
int increase(int x){
   return (-(~x));
}
```

So increment the value with the above-mentioned function and print it.

Apart from my own answer, I found another way to [make an addition with bitwise operators](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-two-numbers-without-using-arithmetic-operators/).

```
int Add(int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0)
        return x;
    else
        return Add( x ^ y, (x & y) << 1);
}
```

Just substitute y with 1 and you get another way of incrementing the value.

Comment: Some may object to you doing someone's obvious homework for them

Comment: @MattMcNabb this makes sense. Have not thought about it.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Great trick. Thanks man, I learnt a lot.