# Can anyone explain type promotion of this program and why output is same

Tags: c++, type-promotion

Why do these two numbers compare as equal and how is the comparison between x and y performed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int  main() 
{ 
   unsigned int x = -1; 
   int y = ~0; //type promotion from int to unsigned int
   if (x == y) 
      printf("same"); 
   else
      printf("not same"); 
   return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ~ operator in C++ (and other C-like languages like C and Java) performs a bitwise NOT operation - all the 1 bits in the operand are set to 0 and all the 0 bits in the operand are set to 1. In other words, it creates the complement of the original number. For more details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3952128/3867787).

> The bitwise NOT operator has an interesting property that when applied
>   on numbers represented by two's complement, it changes the number's
>   sign and then subtracts one (as you can see in the above example).

If you check what the ~-operator does to y like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  main() 
{ 
   unsigned int x = -1; 
   printf("%i\n",x); // treat data as if singed integer
   printf("%u\n",x); // treat data is if unsigned integer

   int y = ~0; //type promotion from int to unsigned int
   printf("%i\n",y);
   if (x == y) 
      printf("same"); 
   else
      printf("not same"); 
   return 0; 
}
```

You can see:

> Success   time: 0 memory: 16064 signal:0
>
> -1 same

Try out [here](http://ideone.com/X9VXwy).

**Why is this so?**

The bit representation for -1 in integer is (see [two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement/1049774#1049774) for details)

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

If you read this in unsigned integer

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

is the largest possible unsigned int. -1 in unsigned int becomes the maximal unsigned int number due to wrap around. Therfore unsigned -1 and int ~0 are the same.