# what is "~0" how does the compiler evaluate it?

Tags: c

Going through K&R C programming book's [Excercise2.1](https://github.com/Mr-Io/c-language-solutions/blob/ed06679e2c946d534370204f9e8f474b114d2a5c/solutions/chapter_2/exercise-2_01/main.c#L17). I tried looking it up but the explanations were a little high level. So what is "~". why does `printf("%u", (unsigned char)~0);` print out `255` and `printf("%u\n", ~0);` prints `4294967295`.

Thank you :)

Comment: thanks. that makes sense. a "tilde" is a bitwise NOT operator but what does `(unsigned char)~0` mean?
thanks again

Comment: An `unsigned char` is an 8-bit unsigned integer (so, a number in the range 0-255). Without that cast, `~0` is a native integer. On a system where that is 32 bits, you get `4294967295`.

Comment: did some googling. `unsigned-char` can go anywhere from 0 to 255. a NOT operator on it just flips all the value so its displayes highest unsigned char that is 255. and binary representation of `~0` in 32 which is 4294967295 in decimal

Comment: That is...exactly what I said.

Answer (score 3):

[What does tilde(~) operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952122/what-does-tilde-operator-do)

TL;DR It's a bitwise not, meaning all the bits are flipped.

For your first example, the `~` operator inverts all 32 bits in the integer 0 (stored as 4 `00000000` bytes), transforming it into all ones (four `11111111` bytes). Then it is cast to an unsigned char, truncating it to just one `11111111` byte. In decimal, `11111111` is 255.
For your second example, the four `11111111` bytes resulting from `~0` is interpreted as an unsigned int, which equals 4294967295 in decimal.

Comment: Prefix `0x` means "Hex" values, and 0x1111 in hex is `0001 0001 0001 0001` in binary.
I think you meant to write `0b11111111`,  because the `0b` prefix means "Binary"

Answer (score 2):

First you should know '~' character is bit-wise NOT

let's see what will happen when we use bit-wise not

```
unsigned char var = ~0;

printf("%u", var); // Output: 255
```

in binary format

```
# 8-Bit Variable

0b00000000 -> 0b11111111
OR
0b11111111 -> 0b00000000
```

or another example

```
0b11001100 -> 0b00110011
```

so we learn that bit-wise NOT reverse every bit in our variable, no matter what bit is 0 or 1 it'll be reverse

now what will happen if we use bit-wise NOT over a larger variable

```
unsigned short var = ~0;

printf("%X", var); // Output: FFFF
```

in binary:

```
0b00000000_00000000 -> 0b11111111_11111111
```

so now you can sure bit-wise NOT don't care about value of variable and size of variable, it just reverse all bits in our variable even if you have a 64-bit variable

Comment: perfectly explained. thanks you very much!

Comment: The claim that `printf("%u", ~var);` outputs 255 is incorrect.  (Test it).  The accompanying explanation has overlooked integral promotions.

Comment: Yes you'r right i forget about `printf` input, answer edited