# Bitwise comparison of binary representation of two numbers

Tags: ruby, bitwise-operators

I was looking for a way to flip all of the bits in an arbitrary-sized number (ie: arbitrary number of bits), and thought of just negating it. When I printed out

```
p ~0b1010 == 0b0101
```

It said `false`. I'm probably using the wrong comparison operator though. What's the proper way to check that two binary numbers are equal in representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[One complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) is not flipping all bits.

To flip bits, you need to use a `xor` operation with an argument with the number of bits 1 you want the significance.

Also you can't negate an binary from arbitrary number. You need to define the number of bits you are flipping. This example will show you why:

```
> 0b000001 ^ 0b1
 => 0 
> 0b000001 ^ 0b11
 => 2 
> 0b000001 ^ 0b111
 => 6 
> 0b000001 ^ 0b1111
 => 14
```

What you can do is define that an arbitrary number of bits is the minimum number of bits you need to represent your number. **This is most likely not what you want**, however, the following code can do this for you:

```
def negate_arbitrary_number(x)
  # size is the number of significants digits you have on x. 
  size = 0
  while (a >> size) != 0
    size += 1
  end

  # this is the binary with all number 1's on 
  mask = ("1"*size).to_i(2)

  # xor your number
  x ^ mask 
end
```

or this code:

```
def negate_arbitrary_number(x)
  x.to_s(2).unpack("U*").map{|x| x == 49 ? 48 : 49}.pack("U*")
end
```

you might want to do a simple benchmark to test it.

Comment: So when the wiki article says `swapping 0's for 1's and vice-versa` this is not what is happening in Ruby when I use the `~` operator?

Comment: That is happening, but the `1` in binary for your computer don't have the bits the way you expected. Computers work with [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/791340/413494) for a more complete explantion

Comment: I think get it. I will specify that the domain of values I am working with is restricted to positive integers only (and usually entered in the form `0b...`, and the only operations I am working with are bit-wise operations (no arithmetics). Given these conditions, it should be sufficient to use the `~` operator to "flip all bits" and correctly perform bit-masking without having to worry about how the computer interprets it?