# What is the ~ operator for

Tags: java, operator-keyword, program-entry-point

Hi all i have for loop with a ~ operator
never found this before on any of the code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        mashed[i] = (byte) ~bytes[i];

        }
```

what does the ~ do?

i haven't found anything like this on the internet or before anywhere
so maybe someone can help me thanks in advance

Comment: As an addition to the posted answers: [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) and [The Java® Language Specification: 15.15.5. Bitwise Complement Operator ~](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.5)

Answer (score 4):

Its an operator of      `~  bitwise NOT`

> The bitwise NOT "~" operator  inverts each bit in the operand i.e. this operator changes all the ones to zeros and all the zeros to ones.

[All operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

And to know how internally works :[How does the bitwise complement (~) operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-work)

Answer (score 2):

It is the [bitwise complement operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Example:

If the value is 2 (0000 0010), the bitwise complement is 1111 1101

Answer (score 2):

From Java's tutorials, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html,

> The unary bitwise complement operator "~" inverts a bit pattern; it can be applied to any of the integral types, making every "0" a "1" and every "1" a "0". For example, a byte contains 8 bits; applying this operator to a value whose bit pattern is "00000000" would change its pattern to "11111111".

Answer (score 1):

It is bitwise operator which will apply not gate on every bit of the data. Eg when data bits are 101, then it will become 010.

Answer (score 1):

The `~` is for bitwise inversion -- 0s become 1s, 1s become 0s.

Answer (score 1):

The `~` operator is bitwise [NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT), it inverts the bits in a binary number:

```
NOT 011100
  = 100011
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html):

> The unary bitwise complement operator "~" inverts a bit pattern; it
>   can be applied to any of the integral types, making every "0" a "1"
>   and every "1" a "0". For example, a byte contains 8 bits; applying
>   this operator to a value whose bit pattern is "00000000" would change
>   its pattern to "11111111".

Answer (score 0):

The Tilde (~) does a bitwise compliment of a numerical value.

```
1011 0011 = ~0100 1100
```