# Adding two numbers without using the addition operator

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, integer-arithmetic

> In c ~ is 1's complement operator. This is equivalent to:   ~a = -b +
>   1 So, a - ~b -1
>   = a-(-b + 1) + 1
>   = a + b – 1 + 1
>   = a + b

Can anyone explains this to me?

Comment: Using a - -b is another way.

Comment: This will only make sense after you understand [two's complement numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-work/791340#791340

Comment: The steps taken by that derivation are a bit odd. `a - ~b -1 = a-(-b + 1) + 1` is valid (and equals `a + b`), but it doesn't really make sense as a step. It looks sort of like it's substituting `~b = -b + 1` (which is incorrect) and sort of accidentally fixing it by changing the subtraction at the end to an addition. Very weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From elementary school math we know

```
a = -(-a);
```

From twos complement we know that

```
-a = (~a) + 1  (invert and add one)
```

so we know that

```
a + b 
= a - (-b)      elementary math
= a - (~b + 1)  twos complement
= a - (~b) - 1   distribute the negative (elementary math)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that `~` is always 1's complement (aka bitwise not) in c. Where you are going wrong is this: C does not guarantee 2's complement for numbers. So all your calculations depend on using a major flavor of C.