# Why does the bitwise complement operator '~' behave differently in c# and java?

Tags: java, c#, operators, byte

When I execute the code in c# and java, I get different output.
In c#, got the output `254` but in java got the output `-2`. Why does it behave differently in term of output? But I want the same output in java means I want output `254`.

In c# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     byte value = 1;
     System.Console.WriteLine("Value after conversion {0}", (byte)(~value));
}
```

**Output : 254**

In Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte value = 1;
        System.out.println((byte)(~value ));
}
```

**Output : -2**

Comment: Helpful: [How does the bitwise complement (~) operator work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-work)

Answer (score 10):

In C# `byte` denotes an *unsigned* 8-bit integer value, i.e. its range is 0-255. In Java, however, a byte is a *signed* 8-bit integer value, i.e. its range is -128-127. -2 (signed) has the same binary representation as 254 (unsigned).

Comment: I would also emphasize that the operator `~` works the same in Java and C#, the only difference is in how `byte` is converted to String in Java and C#.

Answer (score 0):

To get an unsigned 8-bit value in Java you need to do `& 0xFF`

Try

```
System.out.println(~1 & 0xFF);
```

or

```
System.out.println((byte) ~1 & 0xFF);
```