# Why does ~0 return -1?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

This is the code I've tried:

```
int num = ~0;
System.out.print(num);
```

Output: `-1`

From what I understand, `~` inverts the bits. So, `0000 0000` would become `1111 1111`. How is this `-1`? I realize that this is a very basic question that involves two's complement, but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: The most significant bit is worth `-2^31`, not `2^31`.  The rest is just arithmetic.

Comment: Is this question really "what does the ~ operator do," or "why is -1 represented as all 1 bits"? You seem pretty clear on the fact that ~ inverts each bit. This happens completely independently of anything involving two's complement. The fact that all 1-bits represents the integer -1 _is_ two's complement, but that's not what the subject of your question is asking about.

Comment: Because if you add 1 to it, it carries all the way through and you get 0. So `num + 1 = 0`? `num` had better be -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numbers are reprezented in 32 bit format.

To understand why it shows up as all 1 and then get converted to -1.

## Reason:

```
~0 = ~(00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000) = (11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111) = -1
```

To understand more, please read this thread: [How does the bitwise complement (~) operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-work)

Comment: I think you mean _two's_ complement arithmetic.

Comment: I'm still confused.  In **one's** complement arithmetic, `-1` would be `11111111111111111111111111111110`.

Comment: @GaneshKamath It should be two's complement. See the answer that you linked to.

Answer (score 3):

Because `-1` is represented as all ones.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-1));
```

Output is

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Answer (score 1):

1111 1111 is in fact -1 and 1111 1110 is -2. Such is life, not sure how else to put it