# Replace two characters of string with each other in Java

Tags: java, string, bit-manipulation

I have a 32-bit long string of 0s and 1s. I just want this string to be flipped just like binary bits. That is, 0s are to be replaced with 1s and 1s with 0s.
I tried doing this replacement with this code in Java:

```
String flippedBit = StringUtils.replaceEach(PadChar,
        new String[]{"0","1"}, new String[]{"1","0"}, false);
```

But I get this error:

> The method replaceEach(String, String[], String[]) in the type
>   StringUtils is not applicable for the arguments (String, String[],
>   String[], boolean)

Again, I have to store this string in an Integer by first converting it into 32-bit binary.

Comment: So why are you adding the boolean?  `StringUtils` doesn't like it when you add the boolean.

Answer (score 2):

I would iterate the bits of some `int v` and flip them like

```
String str = Integer.toBinaryString(v);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
    sb.append(ch == '1' ? '0' : '1');
}
return Integer.parseInt(sb.toString(), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this [official nuts & bolts tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) provides exactly what you're after:

> The unary bitwise complement operator "~" inverts a bit pattern; it
>   can be applied to any of the integral types, making every "0" a "1"
>   and every "1" a "0".

That is, assuming you're working with the actual bits (in which case this would save you converting to a String and back), and not a String to start with (in which case you're better off with @ElliottFrisch's answer.

Comment: By the way, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/791340/983430) explains in detail how the `~` operator works.