# What is "~" operator in Java

Tags: java, operator-keyword, symbols

Can someone help to explain what "~" does in Java? I searched but couldn't find the answers as I don't know what ~ is called. Thanks in advance. Below is an example from an open source stego program called Snow.

```
private int     tabpos (int n) {
    return ((n + 8) & ~7);
}
```

Comment: Bit wise negation I believe.  So in this case, all but the smallest 3 bits are zero in `~7`.

Comment: check out [the answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-work)

Comment: The "~" character is called a "tilde".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Oracle documentation:

`The unary bitwise complement operator "~" inverts a bit pattern; it can be applied to any of the integral types, making every "0" a "1" and every "1" a "0". For example, a byte contains 8 bits; applying this operator to a value whose bit pattern is "00000000" would change its pattern to "11111111".`

Reference: [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)