# Internal working of Unary Not Operator (~)

Tags: java, operators

```
public class bitwise_operator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int var1 = 42;
        int var2 = ~var1;
        System.out.println(var1 + " " + var2); 
   }
}
```

The above code produces ***42 -43*** as the output.

As far as my understanding goes, ***Unary Not operator*** (**~**), inverts all of the bits of its operand.

Now, ***42*** in binary is ***00101010***. On *using* ***~*** operator, we get ***inverted value of 42***   i.e.  ***11010101***

If you convert the preceding binary value, the output should be something else and not ***-43***

Tried my luck with different numbers to observe the pattern and found that, the ***output is 1 number more than*** the ***initial value supplied*** with a leading ***(-)*** sign before it,  as seen in the above case.

For eg..,

```
if num is 45           // Output is 45 -46
if num is 1001        // Output is 1001 -1002
```

Could someone please explain how the Unary Not Operator (~) works internally to output such results?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-work) question

Comment: *"the output is 1 number more than the initial value supplied with a leading (-) sign"* This hypothesis is correct, but it's usually seen as the other way around. A unary negation is achieved by flipping all the bits and adding one. So e.g. if you want to turn `42` in to `-42` you do `~42 + 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a *signed* integer value which is in 2's complement.

Your result is correct: 11010101 is in fact -43:

-2^7 + 2^6 + 2^4 + 2^2 + 2^0 = -128 + 64 + 16 + 4 + 1 = -128 + 85 = **-43**

Comment: See also [JLS § 15.15.5.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.5): "In all cases, ~x equals (-x)-1."

Comment: @lentz - **`Thanks, that's what I was looking out for !!!`** 
thanks, once again...

Comment: @lentz - **`just to clarify, in case of (~) the calculation begins with the highest bit having`** **(-)**  **`sign to it and rest of the digit has the default positive sign, is that the pattern we follow` ??**

Comment: It is not specific for the ~ operator but for all signed integer in 2's complement: For n bits bn, bn-1,..,b0 is: -2^bn + (2^bn-1 + 2^bn-2 + .. + 2^b0). See more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: @RobinKrahl - **Phenomenal, that was as good as I wanted !!**

Answer (score 0):

This is what's known as two's complement, and it is how integers and all fixed point numbers in Java, C, C++ etc work

```
-x = ~x + 1
```

So for example -1 (0xFFFF) negated bitwise (0x0) plus 1 = 0x1