# Why is the output of this program -4? (Java - Datatypes Byte)

Tags: java, types

I have a doubt in the following code:

```
public class test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    byte x = 3;
        x = (byte)~x;
        System.out.println(x);

    }

}
```

The output is: -4

Comment: Do you understand what binary negation is? What did you expect the output to be?

Comment: 3 is 011 in binary world. Its negation is 100 which amount to 4 in base 10 and in Java it will be not(~) of a 32 bit long 011.

Comment: @Vinay, the negation of 011 in a byte is 11111100, not 100.

Comment: Thats why I have added that it will be a 32 bit negation

Comment: [How does the bitwise complement (~) operator work? Why is it that ~2 is -3?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/791328/995714)

Comment: Thanks, @LưuVĩnhPhúc, for the link. I understand the explanation given there much better than anything written in this thread (sorry, folks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary negation of `numver` is the same as taking negative of `number+1`. Here's why:

Binary 3 is `0011` (leading bits skipped to make it more readable).

Binary negation `~3` is `1100`.

Now, binary 4 is `0100`

To determine -4, firstly write binary negation `1011`.

and then add one (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement%5C)) `1100`