# 0177 versus 177 and their complements

Tags: c

In c, why is that ~177 yields -178, while ~0177 yields -128?

I tried printing out the values before and after, but couldn't discern anything. I also couldn't anything explaining this topic. I am reading "The C Programming Language".

Comment: Because `0` is a prefix for octal notation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constants `177` and `0177` are not the same value.  The former is decimal which the latter is octal.

From section 6.4.4.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *3* A decimal constant begins with a nonzero digit and consists of a sequence of decimal digits. **An octal constant consists of the prefix 0
>   optionally followed by a sequence of the digits 0 through 7 only.** A
>   hexadecimal constant consists of the prefix 0x or 0X followed by a
>   sequence of the decimal digits and the letters a (or A) through f (or
>   F) with values 10 through 15 respectively.
>
> *4* The value of a decimal constant is computed base 10; **that of an octal constant, base 8**; that of a hexadecimal constant, base 16. The
>   lexically first digit is the most significant.

The octal constant `0177` is equal to 127 in decimal.  As a 32-bit hex value, it is represented as 0x0000007f.  Using the `~` operator on this value gives you 0xffffff80.  Assuming 2's complement representation for negative numbers, this is -128 in decimal.

Answer (score 3):

The leading zero indicates that `0177` is an octal number (127).