# What is the Bitwise complement of (-4) i.e. [~(-4)]?

Tags: java

I am new at this portal, I am searching for Bitwise complement of (-4) or any negative number in Java. Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: Why not just print it out and see for yourself?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the bitwise complement operator `~` like

```
int complement = ~ -4;
```

it inverts every bit, that is, a `0` bit turns into `1`, and `1` in a `0`.

Here the [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) and the [Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.5)

If the question is about negative numbers and so, that is, why the result of `~ -4` is `3`, try this [Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/791328/85421) (summary: negative numbers are represented by *two's complement* of the positive one, not just the plain complement {one's complement})