# How to negate a positive integer in C without * or - operators?

Tags: c, integer, bitwise-operators, bit, operation

Hello I am trying to write a function for my lab which requires me to negate a positive number with restricted operators. The operators allowed are: `!` `~` `&` `^` `|` `+` `<<` and `>>`.

My initial approach was to double `x` using addition: `x + x` and then subtracting that from `x` to get the opposite value, but was roadblocked due to the operator restrictions. I am rather new to C and trying to learn, if someone could provide me with the idea behind performing this operation I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Your instructor probably has in mind to assume that your system is using two's complement arithmetic, but technically this is not guaranteed by standard C.  As a start, think about what `~` does if you interpret its input and output numerically.  Try some examples.

Comment: By "inverse" to you mean to get the negative number? That's `(~x)+1`

Comment: Yes, inverse as in 1 -> -1

Comment: Good thread explaining "complement, increment": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-tilde-work

Comment: @Barmar This only works for systems with 2-complement.

Comment: @Barmar just xor the sign bit in sign and magnitude :P

Comment: Ar you allowed to use `INT_MIN`? Are you allowed to use a `while` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not what your instructor wants to see, but it works and it does, unlike the `~` operator, not depend on the implementation (sign-magnitude, 1-complement or 2-complement) and does not cause UB. I post this solution since it meets the requirements but is ugly and slow, because i think the task is stupid (the task leads to functions which only work on systems which use 2-complement, i would bet the instructor presents a solution which only works on 2-complement systems).

```
#include <limits.h>

//Returns the negative value of n,
//n has to be positive. Negative values of n cause UB.
int makeNegative(int n)
{
    int i=INT_MIN;
    while(i+n) //continue till i+n is 0, no need for the < operator
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

If you want code that does not cause UB when `n` is negative, you can check for negative values of `n`:

```
#include <limits.h>

int isNegative(int n)
{
    int i=INT_MIN;
    while(i)
    {
        i++;
        if(n==INT_MAX) //when n reaches INT_MAX, it was positive
        {              //we need to check for it before increment
          return 0;    //increment a int of value INT_MAX would cause UB 
        }
        n++;
        if(!n) //n is 0 means n was negative before
        {
          return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

//Returns the negative value of n i n is positive
//returns n in any other case
int makeNegative(int n)
{
    if(isNegative(n))
    {
        return n;
    }
    int i=INT_MIN;
    while(i+n) //continue till i+n is 0, no need for the < operator
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

### 2-Complement system

As others already pointed out, this is what your instructor probably wants to see: `n=(~n)+1;`. This only works when you are using 2-complement and it causes UB for `INT_MIN`.

Lets say we have the number `1` stored in the variable `n`. Now we want to negate `n`. Then we have to invert the variable, means that we flip every bit and then add `+1`. Here is an example with a `int8_t`.

```
Value | Bit pattern |
    1 |  0b00000001 | n is set to 1
   -2 |  0b11111110 | We inverted n
   -1 |  0b11111111 | We added 1 to n
```

The advantage of a 2-complement system is, that we can use every possible bit pattern for a value and that we can use the same logic for `signed` and `unsigned` variables for most operations. The binary value of `0b11111111` is `0xFF==255` for a unsigned variable. The C standard requires that unsigned integers wrap around. If we store `0xFF` in a `uint8_t` variable and add `1`, the result can't be stored in a `uint8_t` and wraps around to 0. Means `0b11111111+1==0`. As we saw before we can store the value `-1` in a `int8_t` as the bit pattern `0b11111111`. And here we also get `0b11111111+1==0 => -1+1==0`.

One feature 2-Complement systems have is that there is one more negative value than positive values. `INT8_MIN<-INT8_MAX`. `INT8_MIN` has the bit pattern `0b10000000`, if we invert it we get the bit pattern `0b01111111==INT8_MAX`. When we now add `1`, we get an overflow and a overflow causes UB for signed variables*. So the statement `n=(~n)+1;` can causes UB when `n` is signed. The same is true for `n=-n`, `n=n*-1` and `n=n/-1`, since they all fail when n has the lowest possible value which we can not negate.

*When you tell the compiler to use wrap around for signed variables, (`-fwrapv` on gcc), it would result in `INT8_MIN` again.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `INT_MIN+INT_MAX==-1` on systems with 2-complement. I do not see how it causes UB.

Comment: Re “slow”: No, it is not. Apple Clang 11.0 for x86_64 compiles the loop to `negl %eax`.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, as i added in the comments. The task was make a negative value from a positive, there is no need to cover negative input values. In the other hand `~n+1` does not work at all on systems without 2-complement.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: the odds of finding one are abysmally small :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the classic solution you are probably expected to produce:

```
int negate_positive_number(int n) {
    return ~n + 1;
}
```

The problem with this code is it only works on 2's complement systems. This is not a real issue as you are probably not going to encounter other architectures today.

Yet the C Standard supports other representations for signed integers:

- sign/magnitude where negative values have the same value bits set but a sign bit set,
- ones' complement where negative values have all bits reversed from the representation of the positive value.

In both of these historical oddities, there are 2 possible representations for `0`, one of which could be a trap value.

Here is an original solution that works for all 3 architectures: 2's complement, sign/magnitude and ones' complement systems: a bit obscure but more portable:

```
#include <limits.h>

int negate_positive_number(int n) {
    return (n ^ INT_MIN ^ INT_MAX) + (1 & (INT_MIN + INT_MAX));
}
```

It uses `+`, `^` and `&` and the definitions from `<limits.h>`, which might be *off limits*. I assume parentheses are allowed too.

Comment: The task is to do it without `*` (and other constraints), not without `-1`.

Comment: Do you think he cares about 1 complement and magnitude ones?

Comment: Does this cause UB on a system with ones complement, when `n==0` and `0xFFFF` is a trap representation (assuming 16 bit `int`)? Because in this case you would return `0xFFFF`.

Comment: @P__J__: I guess not, I was just surprised to find a more portable alternative, albeit obscure.

Comment: @P__J__ Where would be the fun when you ignore this systems?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: ***6.2.6: Representations of types** [...] Where an operator is applied to a value that has more than one object representation, which object representation is used shall not affect the value of the result. Where a value is stored in an object using a type that has more than one object representation for that value, it is unspecified which representation is used, but a trap representation shall not be generated.* So arithmetic or binary operators cannot produce a trap representation and `1 & (INT_MIN + INT_MAX)` must be `0` on non 2's complement representations.

Comment: @chqrlie Not sure if i understand this correctly, but __6.2.6.2 Integer types__ 4 *If the implementation does not support negative zeros, the behavior of the `&`, `|`, `^`, `~`, `<<`, and `>>` operators with operands that would produce such a value is undefined.* Do i understand as: "creating `0xFFFF` on a 1 complement 16 bit `int` which does not support negative zero causes UB"

Comment: is he allowed to use INT_MIN & MAX?

Comment: @chqrlie IMO it is a basic school question to show students 2's complement numbers. Everything else messes up the poor student brains ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! Very clear now I appreciate the insight.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: good point! it is a problem for `(n ^ INT_MIN ^ INT_MAX)` which produces negative zeroes for `0` itself and `INT_MAX`, thanks to left to right associativity. No easy way around that.

Answer (score 1):

2 complement

```
int minus(int x)
{
    return ~x + 1;
}
```

test:

https://godbolt.org/z/c89GWT

Comment: Be aware that this causes UB when `x==INT_MIN`.

Comment: It is the limitation of the two`s comlement. nothing can be done

Comment: Yes, but you should mention it. Having a limited valid input range is something that happens, but we should always document the the limitations.