# Bitwise operator ~ isn't simply "flipping bits" in python. Why is that?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, bit

I'd expect *bin(~0b111000)* to return the value *0b000111* because to my understanding the NOT operation would return the opposite bit as output.

I keep reading that "*~x*: Returns the complement of x - the number you get by switching each 1 for a 0 and each 0 for a 1" so I don't exactly know where my logic breaks down.

Why does it show -(x + 1) instead of just *literally flipping* all bits?

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: This might help: [BitwiseOperators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the bitwise complement operator (~ tilde) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-tilde-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** flipping all the bits!

You seem to think of `0b111000` as a 6bit value. That is not the case. All integers in python3 have (at least conceptually) infinitely many bits. So imagine `0b111000` to be shorthand for `0b[...]00000111000`.

Now, flipping all the bits results in `0b[...]11111000111`. Notice how in this case the [...] stands for infinitely many **ones**, so mathematically this gets interesting. And we simply cannot print infinitely many ones, so there is no way to directly print this number.

However, since this is 2s complement, this simply means: The number which, if we add `0b111001` to it, becomes `0`. And that is why you see `-0b111001`.

Comment: Now I wonder: could one make python return the actual object to which the bitwise not operation has been applied to? As you said 0b111000 is shorthand for 0b[...]0000111000 where [...] represents a conceptually infinite amount of bits. I´m guessing in practical terms this means that 0b111000 is a pointer to an object that is the value 0b111000, but it is larger than 6 bits in memory. Lets assume that 0b111000 is actually a 32 bit number to which the not operation is applied to - is there any way of making python return the 32 flipped bits instead of the two´s complement in the form of -0bXXXX?

Comment: Well, you could mask it with `& 0xFFFFFFFF`. That would be the value you want, but not the object.